# Attempted import error: 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL' is not exported from '../constants/productConstants.Js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've got no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I'm following a Udemy course for this stuff and I've quadruple checked my code and it looks the exact same to me. Can someone help out?

Here is my productReducers.js code:

```
import {PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL} from '../constants/productConstants.Js';

export const productListReducer = (state = {products:[]}, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return {loading:true, product:[]}

        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {loading:false, products:action.payload}   
            
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

and then my productConstants.js is like this:

```
export const PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST = "PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST"
export const PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS = "PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS"
export const PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL = "PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't be an idiot like me. I had the extension of the productConstants.js file with a capital 'J' (productConstants.Js) and that caused the whole issue.